# How to send 2 variables from a client to the server at the same time using sockets [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, caesar-cipher

Client.py

```
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 65432

ALPHABET = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789.'
message  = 'This message is encrypted using Caesar cipher'        

def encryptstr(message,key):
    #creating a list for new letters
    newletters = []
    #loop to assign new letter value
    for letter in message:
        uppercase = letter.isupper()
        letter = letter.lower()
    #checking if the letter is upper or lower
        if letter in ALPHABET:
            index = ALPHABET.find(letter)
            newindex = (index + key) % len(ALPHABET)
            letter = ALPHABET[newindex]
            if uppercase:
                letter = letter.upper()
        newletters.append(letter)
    #joining the list
    return ''.join(newletters)

def findkey():
    return 10

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
  s.connect((HOST, PORT))
  test = encryptstr(message, findkey())
  s.sendall(test.encode()) # How to send key of 10 and Message?
  data = s.recv(1024)
  print('Received', data.decode())
```

Server.py

```
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 65432

ALPHABET = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789.'

def decryptstr(message,key):
    #creating a list for new letters
    newletters = []
    #loop to assign new letter value
    for letter in message:
        uppercase = letter.isupper()
        letter = letter.lower()
    #checking if the letter is upper or lower
        if letter in ALPHABET:
            index = ALPHABET.find(letter)
            newindex = (index - key) % len(ALPHABET)
            letter = ALPHABET[newindex]
            if uppercase:
                letter = letter.upper()
        newletters.append(letter)
    #joining the list
    return ''.join(newletters)
  
def findkey():
  return 10

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
  s.bind((HOST, PORT))
  s.listen()
  conn, addr = s.accept()
  with conn:
    print('Connected by', addr)
    while True:
      data = conn.recv(1024)
      message = str(data.decode())
      test = decryptstr(message, findkey())
      print(test)
      if not data:
        break
      conn.sendall(data)
```

What I am trying to do with this current code is from the server. I wish to send the variable of "10" to the client. From the client to the server, I would like to send back two variables, one being "10" and the other being the encrypted message. After both are sent, I would like the server to decrypt the message and print it on the screen.

You may be wondering why I would send the ten back and forth, and this is because I will be incorporating this [Diffie-Hellman Example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementation-diffie-hellman-algorithm/) with the `def findkeys()`, Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send that var  in json instead of single var it could help you to send more then 1 data at same time

Answer (score 1):

client ...

```
sock.send(b'10'+encrypted_message)
```

server

```
msg = sock.recv(1024)
code = msg[:2]
encrypted_payload = msg[2:]
```

Is this what you mean?

Comment: Well, kind of? The client still needs to send ```encryptstr(message)``` and the value of 10 to the server. Which the server will then decrypt the message that was sent with the key that was sent. In this case 10 is the key